# Resize a div and all of its children

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that contains 50 other elements. I want the parent div and it's 50 children divs to be resized at once.

For example, when the function resize() is called, "#itemcontainer" and it's children width are assigned a new width, 120%.

My divs:

```
<div id="itemcontainer">
    <div id="item1"></div>
    <div id="item2"></div>
    <div id="item3"></div>
    <div id="item4"></div>
    <div id="item5"></div>
    <div id="item6"></div>
    and so on till item 50
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share your code whatever you have now?

Comment: Please show us some code ....

Comment: try with the .css function of jQuery.

Comment: @sSaroj
That is all I have now. When the function is called i want all of the divs width to be changed to 120%.

Comment: Be aware that if both `#itemcontainer` and its children have `width:120%`, children will overflow `#itemcontainer` and will have a 144% width of `#itemcontainer`'s parent. Not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var container = document.getElementById("itemcontainer");
var boxes = container.getElementsByTagName("div");

function resize() {
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].style.width = "120%";
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DLJqc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 `transform`:

```
transform: scale(1.2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Clicking the button will change the width from the current width (50%) to the parameter width (75%).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Resize child divs</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #itemcontainer > div {
            width: 50%;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function resize(size) {
            $('#itemcontainer > div').css('width', size+'%');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="itemcontainer">
        <div id="item1" style="background-color: green;">
        one
        </div>
        <div id="item2" style="background-color: red;">
        two
        </div>
        <div id="item3" style="background-color: yellow;">
        three
        </div>
        <div id="item4" style="background-color: purple;">
        four
        </div>
        <div id="item5" style="background-color: orange;">
        five
        </div>
        <div id="item6" style="background-color: blue;">
        six
        </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="resize(75);" type="button">Resize</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I gave them colors so it's easier to see what size they currently are. Also, can easily use resize(120) to get the size you are after, however remember than if your container has a fixed width then this will end up with overflow.